# Vuex: How to combine multiple mapGetters while namespaced: true

Tags: vue.js, vuex

There are 3 scenarios that I would like to know **How to combine 2 mapGetters in one**.

**Scenario 1**

One with namespaced: true, one without

```
...mapGetters('cart', ['quantity']),
...mapGetters({
    isLoggedIn: 'isAuthenticated'
})
```

**Scenario 2**

Both with namespaced: true

```
...mapGetters('cart', ['quantity']),
...mapGetters('cart', ['totalSum'])
```

**Scenario 3**

Both with namespaced: true, but each from different module

```
...mapGetters('cart', ['quantity']),
...mapGetters('prods', ['products'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access namespaces like `namespace/key` so

1.

```
  ...mapGetters([
      'cart/quantity',
      'isAuthenticated'
  ])
```

you'll have to access cart quantity like `this['cart/quantity']` or you can rename it by using an object like

```
  ...mapGetters({
      cartQuantity: 'cart/quantity',
      isLoggedIn: 'isAuthenticated'
  })
```

2. 

```
  ...mapGetters('cart', [
      'quantity',
      'totalSum'
  ])
```

3. 

```
  ...mapGetters({
      cartQuantity: 'cart/quantity',
      prodProducts: 'prods/products'
  })
```

Comment: If i do not give it a name, will I be able to access the value of `cart/quantity` by just `{{ quantity }}` in the template?

Comment: For the number 1, what if I want to have `cart/quantity` and `isLoggedIn: isAuthenticated` in a single mapGetters? I noticed that one is in an object while another one is in an array.